# How to write a for loop that skips through BLANK td in BeautifulSoup/Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

The source I am scraping is form forex factory. https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php

There is a table with table rows and table data.

However some table data has no values because they are speeches or events.

How do I write a for loop condition that filters out the BLANK td values.

This is one of the table data tags that is BLANK.

```
for row in table.find_all('tr', {'data-eventid':True}):
list_of_cells = []

#Filtering out High-Impact events and copy its URL link
for span in row.find_all('span', class_='high'):
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath solution to get directly the event ids you're looking for (high impact events, non-blank values) :

```
//tr[td/a[@title='Open Graph'] AND td[@class='calendar__cell calendar__impact impact calendar__impact calendar__impact--high']]/@data-eventid
```

Just add the ids at the end of the URL :

```
https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php#detail=
```

and you're done.